# Rails: Rendering a JS alert

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to render a js alert directly after a user clicks on a submit.

Here's what I have and what I've tried:

That's my erb file.

```
<form action="/welcome/subscribe">
    <div>
        <div id="bottomm">
            <input id="bottom" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Adresse mail" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here's the subscribe method in my controller:

```
def subscribe
  @test = Test.new
  @test.email = params['email']
  @test.save
  binding.pry
  render js: "alert('test)";
end
```

But I get this error:

`Security warning: an embedded <script> tag on another site requested protected JavaScript. If you know what you're doing, go ahead and disable forgery protection on this action to permit cross-origin JavaScript embedding.`

Any idea? :/

edit:

By adding theses 2 lines I can now avoid the warning:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

But now it's redirecting me on a blank page with just written on it:

```
alert('test')
```

Comment: Have you considered having a `subscribe.js.erb` file which does the alert?

Comment: Like rendering the `subscribe.js.erb` ? But if I do this it will redirect and I'd like to stay on the same page but just print out an alert. Is that posible?

Comment: Why would it redirect?

Comment: It will render a new page, am I wrong about that ?

Comment: Yes, it will only redirect if you tell it to.

Comment: Hey, look at your posted error, it is just a warning! any other clue?

Comment: No, I really don't know. I'm just starting rails so I have no clues :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `data-remote` attribute in your form, just add it:

```
<form action="/welcome/subscribe" date-remote="true">
    <div>
        <div id="bottomm">
            <input id="bottom" type="text" name="email" placeholder="Adresse mail" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

## Update

Btw, from the given error, you may add `protect_from_forgery` to your application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  # Other code
end
```

For more detail, please read [this documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf)

Comment: Thanks, Rails already set this up when I did `new rails ... ` So it's already here :)

Comment: Now it works!
I just added `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` but now it's redirecting to a blank page with just `alert('...')` written in it x.x

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that your form will be submitted asynchronously (IE without a full page refresh). When using `form_for` to generate your form, you would include `:remote => true`. Since you are typing out your full form you need to do this:

```
<form action="/welcome/subscribe" date-remote="true">
#...
```